# Alternatives to decision table

Tags: rule-engine, business-rules

Our app is growing rapidly. So, I begun looking into business rules as a way to separate some of our logic from the code (big DAAAH ;). The main goal is to allow our business guys to edit and deploy rules without recompiling anything (another big DAAAH). So far, I could only find references to "decision tables" as a way for business to manage rules. The thing is that I tried to introduce the concept of decision tables to our business and got a very "mixed" response, to say the least :) In short, they don't want to understand them. Question: is there an alternative to decision tables? Something that is easier to understand for sales people?

Comment: If they can't understand decision tables, then they can't fully understand the business rules. Sales people often don't get how complex business logic is. You could might be better off figuring out what types of logic they want to change, and give them a GUI for that. Though with either one, you will end up supporting it.

Comment: That was my argument with their main guy. The main guy replied "They can understand 'If Price = 100 then Buy It' but they won't understand this statement in a table". I had nothing to object with. So, no alternatives to DTs? Just GUI to support it?

Comment: @Byron. In my experience business is almost always not comfortable with Decision tables but they are the ones who must author rules. I agree with you though, that creating a special UI for them is the best way to handle this..

Comment: Not long ago I saw an ASP.NET web control that lets users create rules by selecting rule elements from a menu. Very elegant, with no decision tables at all. I can't remember it's name. Google for "asp.net business rule control" Im sure it's there.

Comment: Would you search your browser's history for the URL, please? :)

Comment: It's http://rule.codeeffects.com

Comment: Is `big DAAAH` like a `big NOPE`? Sorry never encountered this before, not sure if it's meant positively or negatively here. I think `da` is 'yes' in Russian, so a bit more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is only one alternative to decision tables - [decision trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree). Some guys also call them "flow charts", I think. I know several commercial tools that present UI as trees to let users "build" rules with drag-n-drop. Internally though, they convert those trees into decision tables or similarly structured objects when you save rules as files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the rules like the one that you presented in your question go in clusters, such as

1. if Price < 100 then Run
2. if Price == 100 then Buy
3. if Price > 100 and < 120 then Wait
4. if Price >= 120 then Sell

There is easily to put this logic in a decision table with just 2 headers Price and Action. Most of the modern rule engines have support for this kind of decision tables. The experience shows that business users have no problems to understand such tables